# Validate uploaded file extension Yii2

Tags: php, pdf, yii, yii2

I'm trying upload specific files.

This is my code:

```
[['file'], 'file', 'extensions' => ['pdf','php'], 'wrongExtension'=>'pdf,php files only'],
```

When i try upload pdf, works great, but when i try upload php file say: "pdf,php files only". (after click in submit button)
I tried too, txt, js, etc...and i have the same problem.

**print_r($att->file);**

```
yii\web\UploadedFile Object ( [name] => backup-restore-mysql.pdf [tempName] => C:\xampp\tmp\php8364.tmp [type] => application/pdf [size] => 310139 [error] => 0 )
yii\web\UploadedFile Object ( [name] => requirements.php [tempName] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpE22C.tmp [type] => application/octet-stream [size] => 5051 [error] => 0 )
```

**Controller:**

```
if ($att->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $att->validate()){
 $att->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($att, 'file');
    if (!empty($att->file)){
        $extension = $att->file->extension;
        $att->Filename = $att->file->baseName;
        $att->Extension = $extension;
        $att->Size = $att->file->size;
        $att->C_Id = $id;

        if ($att->save()){
            if(!is_dir('files/'.$extension.'/')){
                mkdir(('files/'.$extension.'/'));
            }

            $att->file->saveAs('files/'.$extension.'/'.$att->file->name);
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: By default, Yii will check files and their extensions by [mime type](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/FileValidator.php#L351). Does your server have mime types properly configured? Also, does the server have the `fileinfo` extension installed, as that is used by `[FileHelper](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php#L133)` to do mime type detection. You can look into turning off mime type validation, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: try this way `'extensions' => 'pdf, php'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question by myself.

```
$att->upload_file->saveAs(path,nameOfFile);
$att->upload_file = NULL;
$att->save();
```

Thanks for all replys. @MSost and @G4M1TG